# My debug/release mode switcher got disabled all of a sudden

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm done debugging, now I want to build the release version of the application, but that little combo box used to change from one kind of build to the other is disabled.

I'm writing a WPF application for Windows, written in C#, using

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586
```

here's the screenshot of my VS as asked:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdK37.png

Comment: Are you sure its disabled and not hidden ?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your visual studio and show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8229db22-3111-4e92-a165-859e70aaea97/solution-configurations-and-solution-platforms-grayeddisabled?forum=csharpide)

Ensure "Show advanced build configurations" in Tools->Options->Projects And Solutions->General is checked.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. It seems the last update messed this up on its own, because I didn't even knew this thing existed. Visual Studio updates too damn often, if you pardon my language. You spend the begining of your coding time waiting for it to download and install core updates and extension updates.